# Different domains with same language

Tags: i18n-l10n, domain-access

**Here is my situation**

We have 2 websites: domain.es (use Spanish language) and domain.co.uk (English).
Customer asked us to register new domains: domain.mx (Mexico, so Spanish language) domain.com (English language).

1. We do not want let domain.mx see content from domain.es, but that what will happen, because our views (like all other stuff) are dependent on language.
2. We are considering to filter content by domain using https://www.drupal.org/project/domain however since we never used it before we are not sure if it will cover our needs.

I want to get your opinions guys, how would be best to manage content based on domain level but not a language. So domain.mx and domain.es are completely 2 independent websites and do not share values to each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the .es and .mx content to be unique, you should treat them as different languages.

create a new mx-spanish language type.  even though it is "spanish" the system has no idea,  you can just load the unique content there.

Comment: OK, good one, for some reason I forgot that we could have mx-spanish etc.